# TeamCity build fails for a RIA services project

Tags: wcf-ria-services, teamcity-7.0

I am using RIA services in one of the projects in my solution, which builds perfectly fine on any dev machine. I've also checked the build order, which too looks fine.

I also have a 64 bit, Windows 7 Server where I have installed TeamCity 7.0.3. The same solution fails to build when I run the build agent, and this is an entry from the build log file -

[CreateRiaClientFilesTask] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(303, 5): The 'xxx.csproj' project must be built before client proxy classes can be generated.

However, the client proxy classes are also generated. I can't understand where is the issue. I've tried using MSBuild and VS sln as "Runner Type" in the build step.

NOTE: VS 2010 (along with other necessary SDKs etc.) is installed on the server.

Comment: Related discussion http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5463716#5463716

Answer (score 0):

In solution file (*.sln) move RIA server project 'xxx.csproj' before all client projects.

That way server build is made for 'default targets' instead of 'BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies'.